# Sources for intermediate growth

Tags: group-theory

I want to find sources talking about growth rates which are "true" intermediate growth rates, that is, growths which are both supersupersuper...polynomial and subsubsub...exponential.

The articles I've looked at are only concerned with rates which are superpolynomial and subexponetial.

Anyone know of any papers?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "supersupersuper...polynomial and subsubsub...exponential"?

Comment: For analogy, consider a function $f$ such that $f \circ f(x)= e^x$. This function would have the growth I'm looking for, though there are no analytic solutions, it is just an analogy.